# Two identical PNGs, one is corrupt

Tags: django, angular, png

I have this PNG file, uploaded to a django REST server from an Angular front-end. About 99.9% of uploaded images work fine; you can view them in admin and download them.

But every once in a while, I get these corrupt PNG images. You can see the image if you put the image URL in the address bar but you can't see it on django admin and you can't download it through right click>save.

I uploaded and downloaded the image to Imgur and now it seems to be working. When I put it in the media directory of the Django development server, I can download it with the right click at the image URL.

But *it seems to be identical to the original file!*

- I get nothing with a diff
- File sizes are the same
- Neither of the files seem to be open (checked with `lsof`)

I'm out of options. I uploaded both versions of the images to my google drive and checked that if you download the images, corrupt one still seems to be corrupt. Maybe somebody can figure out what the difference between these files is.

[corrupt image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=12QBQS_HGUqHXrTGp_BFq5_YW52pUrujg)

[saved and fixed image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1V5Z6VITVSRM2PO05cTGwqobos5RVgOdX)

EDIT: After some trial and error, I narrowed down the problem to the file name. Apparently, some filenames give errors but I have no idea why. Here's a list of filenames that work and don't work:

```
a-a14.png # Works
a-a10.png # Works
a-010.png # Works
a-ad0.png # Doesn't work
a-ad4.png # Doesn't work
```

So it seems like if the second, third and fourth characters are `-ad`, the file can't be loaded.

Comment: Not an expert on django, but the files are identical, I just checked the checksum. So then most likely something went wrong inside django, perhaps the saving of the url into the database? Unsupported characters comes to mind

Comment: In production, the files are served by nginx and the same thing happens there too. I also tried changing the url to no avail.

Comment: OK, it is related to the filename. When I remove the hyphen, it works. But there are other files with hyphenated names so I don't yet know why this one is causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

The problem boils down to file name. Apparently if the file name matches the regexp `/.*-ad[0-9].png/`, it is not loaded. Problem persists both on django and nginx serving files.

I opened a new question for this: [Images that fit the regexp `/.*-ad[0-9]\.png/` can not be loaded in any browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227131/images-that-fit-the-regexp-ad0-9-png-can-not-be-loaded-in-any-browser)