# Images that fit the regexp `/.*-ad[0-9]\.png/` can not be loaded in any browser?

Tags: django, web, server, png

I had this [weird problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57225167/two-identical-pngs-one-is-corrupt) of identical PNG images created with `drf-extra-fields`'s `Base64ImageField` with different file names not being loaded.

Problem persists both in Django development server and nginx serving the image files so I don't think it is specific to Django or nginx.

I experimented with different file names and some work and some don't:

```py
0-ad0.png # Doesn't work
a-ad0.png # Doesn't work
aaaaaa-ad0.png # Doesn't work
0-ae0.png # Works
0-bd0.png # Works
0-ada.png # Works
a-ad.png # Works
a-ad00.png # Works
```

As far as I can tell, if the file name fits this regular expression, it is not loaded: `/.*-ad[0-9]\.png/` Did anyone encounter such a thing? What could be the reason for this?

EDIT: here's what firefox is showing me:
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting? Do all the files have the same permissions?

Comment: I'm getting no errors. Chrome doesn't even tell me that it doesn't load the image. On Firefox you can see a notification in the inspector that the image is not loaded but there is no broken image icon on the page. All files have same permissions. I'm changing the name by copying files and it doesn't work if the name fits the regexp.

Comment: I've added what firefox is showing in dev tools in the question.

Comment: Are you getting error in your browsers network tab? How are you serving the files?

Comment: No error in the network tab. And the problematic image is not showing there. I'm serving the files with nginx here but the same problem shows even on Django dev server locally.

Comment: When you say that no error is appearing in the network tab, what do you mean? The browser is successfully requesting the image and there is not a 404/500?

Comment: There seems to be no request to the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have an ad blocker enabled? "-ad0." is in the adblock plus list.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem! Nice catch!